# Android WeakReference not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, weak-references

As I know, from the spec (and from the standard non-android) java, If an object is only "Weak Referenced", that is, only reachable by weak references - it **will** be collected by the garbage collection the next time it runs.

In my android app, for some reason, This is not the case.

A quite heavy object (Activity) stays in the heap every time its created, but when I perform a heap dump and examine it in the Eclipse Memory Analyzer I see that the object remained in the heap, **even though it's only weak referenced** (as can be seen in merge paths to GC roots option)

When I explicitly clear the weak reference, the object gets cleared.

I run my app on Android 2.3.3. It looks like a some kind of platform bug.

Am I missing something? 
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Thanks,
Yoav

Comment: "I see that the object remained in the heap", what kind of object? Bitmap references?

Comment: An activity. That was only weak referenced.

Answer (score 0):

> *it **will** be collected by the garbage collection the next time it runs.*

No, there are no such guarantees. It *may* be collected. (This holds for all objects, regardless of reference types, and it's the reason why you often read that an object becomes "*eligible* for collection".)

Comment: I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError because it is **never** collected

Comment: Is it different from what is guaranteed by standard (non-android) java?

Comment: If you get `OutOfMemoryError`s i suggest you use `SoftReference` instead of `WeakReference`. Android tries to clear the `SoftReference`s before throwing `OutOfMemoryException`s and only throws the error if it couldn't clean up enough space.

Comment: Are you saying that android clears SoftReferences **before** WeakReferences?